# UITextfield Bad Access on overriding text property

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitextfield, textfield

This is what i have done in my subclass of UITextfield,

```
override public var text:String?  {
didSet {            
     NSLog("text = \(text)")
}
willSet {
    NSLog("will change from \(text) to \(newValue)")
}}
```

Now when i use myTextField.text to set the value to a variable, it shows Bad Access. When i log the text, It shows some garbage value as text.

Answer (score 1):

Look at this subclass of UITextField.

```
//  CustomTextField.swift

import UIKit

class CustomTextField: UITextField {
    override internal var text : String? {
        didSet {
            if !(text != nil && text!.isEmpty) {
                print("text = \(text)")
            }

        }

    willSet {
        if !(text != nil && text!.isEmpty) {
            print("will change from \(text) to \(newValue)")
        }
    }

}
}
```

I checked on View Controller. It Works:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        sampleTextField.text = "sample Text -1"
    }
    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        sampleTextField.text = "sample Text - 2"
    }
```

Comment: I had the issue when i tried like **myData.name = textField.text**

Comment: try saving textfield.text to a string and assigning to the variable.